# Can't catch java.lang.NullPointerException on Android

Tags: android, exception, progressdialog

Error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lala.Home.hideLoadinganimation(Home.java:969)
    at com.lala.Home.access$4(Home.java:967)
    at com.lala.Home$17.onFinish(Home.java:892)
    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage   (AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:180)
    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$1.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:86)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know why it happens, somehow user hides/exits or goes to some other app just as my app finished loading data from server and just about to hide progress dialog.

I am trying to catch it in below block but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
   private void hideLoadinganimation(boolean asDialog) {
    try {
        if (asDialog) {
            try {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // again, sometimes pDialog is null. I have no idea why as I
                // can't reproduce it.
            }
        } else {
            switcher.showPrevious();
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: is your hideLoadinganimation method in different thread?

Comment: Where is the stacktrace you provided coming from? Is it in a log file? If so, which one?

Comment: which is line Home.java:969 then we can suggest any thing.....

Comment: Noby no, same. John stack trace coming from ACRA remotely posted

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh thanks! I went to check the line and noticed that error logs coming from an older version of the app. Although I force user to update when there is a new version, couple of users some how bypassing it.

Comment: @nLL You can answer your own question, but you won't be able to accept your own answer for a few days. If this is the answer, please post it as an answer and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 1):

i think your `pDialog` is null.

try to

```
if(null!=pDialog && pDialog.isshowing()){

      pDialog.dismiss();

}
```

Comment: This is the proper way to handle it (faster, safer, cleaner).  However, I am curious why the try-catch is falling through and crashing the app despite it being a catch-all.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  pDialog.dismiss();
```

To

```
if(pDialog!=null)
{
  pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

But you need to figure out why it is getting null

Answer (score 0):

After Dheeresh Singh's comment, I went to check the line and noticed that error logs coming from an older version of the app. Although I force user to update when there is a new version, couple of users some how bypassing it. Sorry for the hassle.

I should have spent some more time on it and check details.